# Falling Factorial Notation

Tags: notation, pochhammer-symbol

If $(x)_{n}$ refers to

$$x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$$

then what does $(xy;x)_{n}$ refer to?

Is it

$$xy(xy-1)\ldots(xy-n+1)?$$

Thanks.

The notation in question is used on page two of [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9090065P).

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard usage. Where did you find it?

Comment: I have added a link to the paper I found it in.

Comment: Your interpretation is not plausible as the second argument isn't used.

Comment: It looks like a q-Pochhammer symbol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol

Comment: Why was the question downvoted? It's a valid question, I looked at the linked paper, the notation is there. @ChristopherCarlHeckman already gave the answer in his comment it seems

Comment: @Benedict I find your comment pretty rude. Even if it's just for curiosity, the question is certainly worth asking.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Comments are as valid as the question. Satisfying someone's passing curiosity doesn't warrant spending time answering, in my view. But don't let me stop you if that is what you want to do. Needless to say, the questioner may yet come up with more noble reasons to know.

Comment: @Benedict The thing that really bothers me about what you write is that, while you assert that your time is worth too much to spend it answering a passing curiosity, you still throw it away commenting. I can accept the fact that you don't want to take the time to write down an answer, but at least don't be so inconsistent and avoid writing anything entirely.